# Add an "Off-topic" option to the top level of Close popup

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, off-topic

Every time when I have to close a (blatantly) off-topic question I spend time finding this option inside Close question popup. Currently it's "*A community-specific reason*" and then (on the next level) "*This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.*"

If there're other votes it's easy, because I see that votes count next to the option. This count works like an indicator helping me to select right option:

> [image]

However, in case when my vote will be the first one every time I read that long string entirely to be sure that I'll made a right decision:

> This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.

Could we please migrate (or copy) that option to the top level of Closing popup:

> [image]

Or at least add a "**Off-topic**" sentence in bold as a starting string for that option:

> [image]

Such modifications will make me (and you) more productive when closing the question as (blatant) off-topic when needed.

Comment: Especially on main meta, dozens per day. I think it would count as a [tag:workflow] issue.

Comment: @W.O. I think a lot of the regulars don't notice case we have a script for OT stuff on meta

Comment: On sites where you don't have much rep, you can still actually get to the old 'Blatantly off topic' reason [but it's many clicks deep]. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl8Tr.png

Comment: Completely absent on [scifi.se], you have to write a custom reason.

Comment: @W.O. - no, it's still there; you just have to dig deep for it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtSMu.png These all vanish once you have enough rep & get 'close vote' privs.

Comment: Oh, never noticed it was a rep issue. Thanks for clarification @Tetsujin